# using java how to write fallback mechanism to connect http url

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

In my code, I need to connect one url say http://example.org . If the above url doesn't connect (connectivity issue or server down), I need to connect another url say http://example-1.org .

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.org");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();

int code = connection.getResponseCode();
if (code != 200){
//try alternate url connection here.
}
```

Please suggest improved way to do my usecase.

Also in case the first url has not been connected for n times (or n minutes), then I need to connect the alternate url afterwards. I'll have property(will have value in DB) to set the connectivity of first url has failed. once the first url is up, then I manually change the value in DB  to connect the first url.

Please help me.

Comment: @Buddy I have given my code above. I need better one to do it

Comment: Possibly duplicate [Fallback Mechanism - Best approach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967212/fallback-mechanism-best-approach)